# Getting a full trace (every line) from ollydbg

Tags: ollydbg, tracing

When I use the ollydbg run trace I don't seem to he getting every single line as I expect to. First off let me explain what Iexpect to see:

```
Address hexDumb Command comments EAX ECX etc...
0042AD43 BLAH JNZ 00112345 somecomment 01010101 10101010... etc....
0042AD48 FLAH XOR EAX, ECX anothercomment 01010101 10101010... etc...
```

Essentially each line from the CPU window, all of the data that you see for each line.

When I step into each command by hand in ollydbg then I get to see each command of the thousands that are executed. However when I use the run trace I get a hand ful of commands, somewhere in the range of 50 commands.